# str_detect returns more values than expected when pattern contains unicode

Tags: r, stringr

We're trying to parse a vector of names that contain unicode and are getting some weird results. When we search for `\xf6` the vector below comes back with three, instead of two `TRUE` values. What are we missing?

```r
library(tidyverse)

name_list <- c("Atomi", "Besser", "Bj\xf6rkroth", "Bjorkroth", "Brakhage", "Cann", "Cullen", "Dozois", "Drake", "Dudley", "Elkins", "Elliot", "Goodrich-Blair", "Griffiths", "Kelly", "Kivisaar", "Kostka", "L\xf6ffler", "Liu", "Loeffler", "Lovell", "M\xfcller", "Macfarlane", "Master", "McBain", "Nojiri", "None", "Parales", "Pettinari", "Schaffner", "Schloss", "Schottel", "Spormann", "Stabb", "Stams", "Vieille", "Voordouw", "Wommack", "Zhou")

str_detect(name_list, "\xf6")
#>  [1] FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
#> [12] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
#> [23] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
#> [34] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE



> sessionInfo()
R version 3.5.0 (2018-04-23)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0 (64-bit)
Running under: macOS High Sierra 10.13.5

Matrix products: default
BLAS: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.5/Resources/lib/libRblas.0.dylib
LAPACK: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.5/Resources/lib/libRlapack.dylib

locale:
[1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
 [1] reprex_0.2.0    forcats_0.3.0   stringr_1.3.1   dplyr_0.7.5    
 [5] purrr_0.2.5     readr_1.1.1     tidyr_0.8.1     tibble_1.4.2   
 [9] ggplot2_2.2.1   tidyverse_1.2.1

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] tidyselect_0.2.4 reshape2_1.4.3   haven_1.1.1      lattice_0.20-35 
 [5] colorspace_1.3-2 htmltools_0.3.6  rlang_0.2.1      pillar_1.2.3    
 [9] foreign_0.8-70   glue_1.2.0       withr_2.1.2      modelr_0.1.2    
[13] readxl_1.1.0     bindrcpp_0.2.2   bindr_0.1.1      plyr_1.8.4      
[17] munsell_0.5.0    gtable_0.2.0     cellranger_1.1.0 rvest_0.3.2     
[21] devtools_1.13.5  evaluate_0.10.1  psych_1.8.4      memoise_1.1.0   
[25] knitr_1.20       callr_2.0.4      parallel_3.5.0   broom_0.4.4     
[29] Rcpp_0.12.17     clipr_0.4.0      backports_1.1.2  scales_0.5.0    
[33] debugme_1.1.0    jsonlite_1.5     mnormt_1.5-5     hms_0.4.2       
[37] digest_0.6.15    stringi_1.2.3    processx_3.1.0   rprojroot_1.3-2 
[41] grid_3.5.0       cli_1.0.0        tools_3.5.0      magrittr_1.5    
[45] lazyeval_0.2.1   crayon_1.3.4     whisker_0.3-2    pkgconfig_2.0.1 
[49] xml2_1.2.0       lubridate_1.7.4  rmarkdown_1.10   assertthat_0.2.0
[53] httr_1.3.1       rstudioapi_0.7   R6_2.2.2         nlme_3.1-137    
[57] compiler_3.5.0
```

Comment: I only get two `TRUE` when running your code (as expected) with stringr_1.3.1

Comment: I'm running 1.3.1 and I also get 3. The third match is `"M\xfcller"`. I'm on a Mac R 3.5.0 and in a US_eng locale. Also grep refuses to accept that pattern as valid in my locale: `grep("\\\xf6", " ")` gives an error while `grep("\\\x20", " ")` gives the expected result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pass it as a fixed pattern:

```
which(str_detect(name_list, "\xf6"))
# [1]  3 18 22

which(str_detect(name_list, fixed("\xf6")))
# [1]  3 18
```

Comment: Agree this succeeds. Which is interesting because `name_list[grep("\xf6", name_list, fixed=TRUE)]` throws an error.

Comment: @42 that is interesting. in `grep()`, it tries to evaluate `pattern`, here `"\xf6"` before it does anything with the value of `fixed`.  When passing `fixed(pattern)` to `str_detect()`, though, there is no attempt to evaluate `pattern` as a regex.

Comment: Thanks @DanHall - this works. Is this a bug? Looking at https://stringr.tidyverse.org/articles/regular-expressions.html#special-characters, I would have thought it would "just work".

Comment: @PatS Not a bug in `stringr`. The issue is in the regex engine. `str_detect` defaults to evaluate its `pattern` argument (here `"\xf6"`) as a regular expression. You are looking to match the literal pattern (i.e., *fixed* pattern) `"\xf6"`.  The way to do that in the `stringr` package, and with `str_detect`, is to pass the pattern to `fixed()` first.  The odd behavior here is that, in a Mac OS, base r's regex engine (and anything that relies on that) chokes on `"\xf6"` as a regular expression.